# SAS merge on another variable if one missing (proc sql step)

Tags: merge, sas, missing-data

I try to merge SDC IPO data to Compustat on cusip codes. SDC offers both cusip9 (with some missings) and cusip6 (no missings), and Compustat only cusip9. I substring Compustat to get "my own" cusip6 variable in Compustat. However, I would rather first merge on the given cusip9, and only in case there is a missing in cusip9, then merge on cusip6. 
So far, my code is the standard merging code on a proc sql step:

```
proc sql;
    create table sdc_comp
    as select   a.*, b.*
    from compustat as a left join sdc as b
    on a.cusip9 = b.cusip9
    order by ipodate, gvkey, fyear;
quit;
```

Any suggestions? If a data step would do this better, no problem with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find the coalesce / coalescec functions useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [coalsece](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/fedsqlref/67364/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1sggqfsihp9h8n1fc3hp5vpzdqp.htm) function. It will return first nonmissing value (it will work in your case with numeric values). Try to get cusip6 value then try to get cusip9 afterwards.
It will look like: `SELECT COALESCE(cusip6, cusip9);`